# Who won the election?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The [election](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1) recently ended, and there is lovely file of the results, but it looks like this when displayed in the browser.

```
4 3
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 4 3 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 4 2 1 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 3 2 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 4 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 2 3 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 1 2 4 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 4 0
1 3 4 2 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 2 1 4 0
1 1 2 0 0
1 1 2 4 0
1 2 1 4 0
1 1 2 4 0
1 2 0 0 0
1 3 1 2 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 1 3 4 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 1 3 4 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 4 1 0
1 2 1 4 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 2 3 0 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 1 0 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 3 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 3 1 2 0
1 2 3 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 1 4 0
1 2 3 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 1 2 0 0
1 1 4 2 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 4 3 0
1 3 1 2 0
1 2 1 4 0
1 2 0 0 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 4 2 3 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 2 4 1 0
1 3 4 2 0
1 3 1 2 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 1 3 2 0
1 2 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 3 1 4 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 3 2 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 3 4 0
1 2 0 0 0
1 2 4 1 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 3 2 1 0
1 4 0 0 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 4 2 1 0
1 1 2 3 0
1 1 2 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 4 3 1 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 3 1 2 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 1 4 0
1 4 3 0 0    
1 2 1 4 0
1 1 2 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 2 0 0 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 2 3 1 0
1 3 1 4 0
1 2 1 3 0
1 3 4 1 0
1 3 1 2 0
1 4 3 2 0
1 4 0 0 0
1 2 4 1 0
1 2 1 3 0
0
"iKlsR"
"gandalf3"
"David"
"NoviceInDisguise"
"Blender Stack Exchange Moderator Election 2015"
```

That is obviously not the most useful information, unless you know what it means, unfortunately I do not, so my question is, **How can these results be read in a remotely useful form?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the votes were still being tallied, the results can now be viewed [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/750/599).

For more detail about the exact algorithm used, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek). For an explanation of the file format used to store the votes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234236/2730823).

Comment: your first sentence answers my original question (pre-edit)