# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Blender's [first moderator election](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: iKlsR] [image: gandalf3] [image: David]

They've replaced [the pro-tempore crew](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) — please thank **both** teams for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new crew as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6496527652487168/0).

Answer (score 7):

Congrats to the new moderators.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to all the pro-tem mods who helped get this site to where it is today!